# How to move files from one folder to another in Scala

Tags: java, scala

I am new to Scala.

I googled a lot but only found how to move files in Java. I tried to move files using Java:

`import Java.io.File`

and both:
`Files.move("FileA", "FileB",StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);` and `Files.move("DirA", "DirB",StandardCopyOption.ATOMIC_MOVE);`

How do I move files from one folder to another in Scala?

Answer (score 1):

If you have to do a lot of file handling I recommend https://github.com/pathikrit/better-files.

It would be as easy as

```
import better.files._
File("/path/one/file").moveToDirectory(File("path/two"))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Java API in Scala to move files from one location to another. Below is the code to do the same,

```
import java.io.File
import java.nio.file.{Files, StandardCopyOption}

val source = new File("path-to-source-directory").toPath
val destination = new File("path-to-destination-directory").toPath
Files.move(source, destination, StandardCopyOption.ATOMIC_MOVE)
```

Answer (score 0):

An easy way is to use sys proecess build in scala.
Just like using bash.

If you want to move "1/1.txt" to "2"

```sh
$ tree
.
├── 1
│   └── 1.txt
└── 2
```

In scala REPL:

```scala
scala> import scala.sys.process._
import scala.sys.process._

scala> "tree".!!.mkString
res0: String =
".
├── 1
│   └── 1.txt
└── 2

2 directories, 1 file
"

scala> "mv 1/1.txt 2".!!
res1: String = ""

scala> "tree".!!.mkString
res2: String =
".
├── 1
└── 2
    └── 1.txt

2 directories, 1 file
```

It's a little different to move files to another directory.

```scala
scala> "tree".!!.mkString
res3: String =
".
├── 1
└── 2
    ├── 1.txt
    └── 2.txt

2 directories, 2 files
"

scala> Seq("/bin/sh", "-c", "mv 2/* 1").!!
res6: String = ""

scala> "tree".!!.mkString
res7: String =
".
├── 1
│   ├── 1.txt
│   └── 2.txt
└── 2

2 directories, 2 files
"
```

See also here: 
https://alvinalexander.com/scala/how-to-handle-wildcard-characters-running-external-commands